# The meaning of the "<object>" operator in Java

Tags: java, android, operators

With the fear of sounding stupid.
Recently, I started with java/android.
I am loving it, but for the love of all that is good, I have come across an operator i can't seem to understand.
The thing is, I do not even know the name of it, so googling for it has been close to impossible. I have not found anything about it, not because it is not there, but because I do not even know where to start.

The operator is `<someObject>`. The same operator used in `List<object>`.
I actually became fascinated with it when using the AsyncTask class in android where I had to do something like

```
MyClass extends AsyncTask<String[], Drawable[], Drawable[]>{
     ...
```

Any info on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please search the web for "Java generics"

Comment: *Generics* and *parametized types* should point you to good resources. Fully understand, that you need a *term* to start searching :)

Comment: Thanks to @Mat and andreas_D. Those are great starting points

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not an operator - it's how you specify a generic type parameter.

It's probably best to start off with the [Generics part of the Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html), then [Gilad Bracha's paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf&ei=PE0yT8baMYyE8gOQja3fBg&usg=AFQjCNHlDA-kbX-h4ixgUmBJK6VZNRVENw&sig2=FpKqa87svLLhxwIJdINgaw), then consume the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for anything else. (There are *lots* of knotty corners in Java generics.)

Comment: Thanks. Coming from a scripting background, I must say I am enjoying java. It just has different (though refreshing) features that I am taking time to understand. Thanks for the patience and help. Appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It is not an operator, it is how you declare a parameterized type.

Before Java 5, you coulnd't say that your List was a "List of something", just a List with no type. So when you took an object out of your list, you had to cast it back to a specific type :

```
List strings = new ArrayList();
strings.add("hello");
String s = (String) strings.get(0);
```

With Java 5, you can specify the type of the elements, using angular brackets :

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("hello");
String s = strings.get(0);
```

Because you know the exact type of the elements now, you don't have to cast the objects you get from the list anymore. Plus, the compiler won't let you add incompatible objects in the list :

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add(42);   // Compiler error : expected a String, got an int
```

Answer (score 2):

It's to do with generic types and type safety.

In "old java" you just had a List and it contained Objects - not type safe.

```
List l = new List();
l.add(new Type1()); // valid
l.add(new SomeOtherType()); // valid
```

These days you say

```
List<Type1> l = new List<Type1>();
l.add(new Type1()); // valid
l.add(new SomeOtherType()); // invalid since it is a list of Type1
```

The items in the List can be Type1 or any of it's subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then `List<Object> myList = new List<Object>` means `myList` can hold `Objects` or any of its subclasses. This means myList can hold any object as they're all subclasses of `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Java 1.5, Java's collection classes were "untyped" (technically they still are). They could only store items that were derived from java.lang.Object.  This was a bit cumbersome as you were forced to cast Object to your assumed contained type. This lead to all kinds of issues and oddities here and there.

Sun (now Oracle), added a "trick" to the language that would allow developers to specify a "type" for a container or other object. As I said, this is a "trick", the compiler performs type safety checks but in reality there is no change to the signature of the object emitted. It cleans up the code and adds a small amount of type safety but in reality its nothing more than a parlor trick.

Look up the Generics documentation provided with the JDK and the tutorials available.